# Windows Mobile application icon

Tags: .net, windows-mobile, compact-framework, icons

Is it possible to specify the application icon for a windows mobile app from a resource file or other configuration besides the .csproj?

The reason I would like to do this is because I have an application that can be configured to run in several different ways.  We would like to build out three unique .cabs based on these configurations, and we would like to use a different icon for each version.

One option we've considered is just running multiple builds and swapping out the icon file each time, but we were hoping there would be a way to do this using a "resource" DLL or something along those lines, that could be compiled or linked in to the main .exe.